# I am a physically dying human. Will I limit myself to consideration of physics or will I consider that which is extra-physical?

Tags: physics, life, death

Humanity has understood the physics of proton bound to neutron orbitted by electron as atom. As a human aware of my impending demise, I determined to consider is death or cessation of mere physical interaction all that there is or is there ongoing broader extra-physical existence and interation. It has been provided that I have been enabled to experience and understand that there is, by the One who always was and is in extra-physical existence and who, also, inhabited or made for Himself a physical vessel that He might temporally provide for empirical interaction observable by physically constricted mere physical senses. I, mere human that I am, could let myself get a headache in my considerations and desire to communicate my understandings that humanity might know peace or freedom from anxiety.

Comment: I don't know if this will be closed or not, but you might get something from the philosopher Ernst Bloch. The "not yet".  I will translate it out of his language to our language:  the "Kingdom of God" (defeat of death) will be in this world, not in heaven. This will occur through the dialectic.  This is a kind of mix of Jewish faith and Hegel. (on the one hand the Messiah is "not yet, the full capabilities of the dialectic (as it moves in nature) is also "not yet". Not yet but possible.

Comment: Key:  the dialectic overcomes death on the material plane. No supernaturalism is required. Only time is required.

Comment: Christ defeated death by means of His crucifixion and resurrection, so we don't need to concern ourselves with the dubious dialectic of Hegel.

Comment: This is a kind of personal question that one can only answer for oneself and it sounds like you already answered it for yourself. So what is your question for SE?

Comment: Didacticly I must reply we may say not yet to dead until we are. One who was dead, is animate, and is enabled physical interaction not bound by normal physics(touching, being touched, passing  through walls, and ascending beyond universe) is a one which is more than physical matter or mere physical human such as we. That this one can re-enable physical matter for human physical interaction within the physical realm and beyond is the only plausible possibility I've heard.

Comment: For conifold, will SE permit me muse that an other may consider how we are going to lay down the time we have? Have you considered whether there is more at play than mere physical and if so what is your understanding of the physical and extra -physical.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for personal opinions on the question of materialism vs. dualism, which is known to be an outstanding question with literally thousands of texts written on it from both sides.

Comment: To Gordon, my understanding of heaven is planetary atmosphere, space, and that which is beyond universe so heaven is here.

Comment: To Mr Ammon, that it is not perceived by mere physical means of observation does not prevent that there may be more at play than meets the eye. When enabled perception by observation via extra-physical or extended means it becomes empirical evidence.